# C++ reference variables

Tags: c++, reference, compiler-errors

I have these two functions (with Point2D & LineVector (has 2 Point2D member variables) classes and SQUARE macro predefined)

```
inline float distance(const Point2D &p1,const Point2D &p2) {
    return sqrt(SQUARE(p2.getX()-p1.getX())+SQUARE(p2.getY()-p1.getY()));
}

inline float maxDistance(const LineVector &lv1,const LineVector &lv2) {
    return max(distance(lv1.p1,lv2.p2),distance(lv1.p2,lv2.p1));
}
```

but it gives compilation error in maxDistance() function (line 238) saying:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include/c++/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h: In instantiation of `std::iterator_traits<Point2D>':
quadrilateral.cpp:238:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include/c++/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:129: error: no type named `iterator_category' in `class 
Point2D'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include/c++/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:130: error: no type named `value_type' in `class Point2D
'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include/c++/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:131: error: no type named `difference_type' in `class Point2D'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include/c++/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:132: error: no type named `pointer' in `class Point2D'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include/c++/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:133: error: no type named `reference' in `class Point2D'
```

Please suggest what is the error?

Comment: @AndreyT: How so? It looks like perfectly real code to me.

Comment: I got the error. Actually the distance is already a function in std namespace. I did not know that thing. Now when I change the name of distance function, it works. It is a real code BTW.

Comment: Just because `distance` is a standard function does not mean that you should get the conflict. Firstly, the standard function is in `std::`. Secondly, your argument types should eliminate any possibility of the ambiguity between your `distance` and the standard one, even if you do `using namespace std;`. Yet, you get the error. I don't see how it is possible. There's something you are not telling us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you may be calling std::distance instead of your own distance function.  There are a few reasons why this might be happening, but it's usually because of gratuitous use of

```
using namespace std;
```

Try explicitly using the namespace or class name when calling the distance function, or if it's in the global namespace

```
float result = ::distance(point1, point2);
```

Comment: Or (best option): Get rid of `using namespace std;`. It makes code in books look prettier, but there's a reason the standard library is in a namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Point2D needs to inherit from `std::iterator` before it's going to place nicely with std::distance. `std::distance` needs some of the typedefs provided by the standard iterator type in order to use the correct method for measuring the distance.

EDIT: I'm assuming Point2D is supposed to be an iterator. If you're assuming `std::distance` is the distance formula, you are mistaken. `std::distance` returns the difference in position between two iterators pointing to a common container.

Comment: I did not understand anything. Please elaborate. The code looks perfectly fine to me then why this strange error?

Comment: Okay you are saying that distance is already a function in standard library?

Comment: Yes, `std::distance` is already part of the standard library: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/distance/ That's why it's in namespace std, so you can define your own function called distance if you want. You don't have any `using namespace std` s around, do you? :)

Comment: @GMan: Ow! Get off my toes! (And maybe I'll get off yours)

Comment: @GMan: LOL! You didn't have to *delete* it. *Bill is cracking up*

Comment: No actually I have namespace std. I got it.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: It doesn't matter whether the standard `distance` is in `std::` or not. C++ supports function overloading, based on argument types. If the code is indeed as the OP describes it, the call in the OP must resolve to the OP's `distance`, not to `std::distance`. `using namespace std` cannot affect that in any way.

Comment: @AndreyT: That's not what the OP is claiming. Honestly, when I wrote this answer, I paid more attention to the error message than the code (Which is evident in the first part of the answer :) ) I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe compiler interprets distance call as std::distance? Do you have using namespace std before this code? Try to rename the distance function and see what happens.

Comment: I think it is obvious that the compiler interprets the call as `std::distance`. No doubt about that. Yet I don't see how it can interpret it that way given the above code.